# How do I format my flash drive?

Tags: usb, flash, format

So it seems like my 32GB Flash drive has something wrong with it and its registered as full even though im only using 1.7gbs. Now you may think it might not be that big of a deal but I need it to move my files around and to store my photos and videos on etc...

I was told formatting it might help but im not sure exactly how to on Ubuntu 14.04

If it helps in anyway when I was making my flash drive a bootable device it was renamed as 'UUI'

Thank you very much for reading this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case that you have not done this already,
install the `GNOME partition editor` tool.

Open GParted - select the USB flash drive.
Right-click the partition - select unmount.

[image]

Right-click the partition - select format to.
Choose fat32 - Click on Apply in menu bar.

[image]